# How to add an event that's created on one view but being displayed from a different view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a ViewController that will be adding two subviews (UIViews) to it depending on what goes on. I want the subview to have UIButtons with events on it but when I do:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(switchCategory:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

on the subview, nothing responds when the button is pressed.

How do I get this working?

To be more specific, the files would be UIViewController, UIViewA, UIViewB and each UIView file will have its own events. and in the Controller I'm just doing addSubview:UIViewA/UIViewB

Comment: Are you sure `button` is in single quotes like that: `'button'`?

Comment: I was just saying button with quotes meaning the buttons name. but all my code seems correct, its just not activating any events at all when touching the button. not sure If i have to add any delegates or something

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix for it. Being that I didn't give my view a size, it wasn't processing the events.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with UIView actions/animations, there are 2 main things that you are doing:

1: Make sure you give it a frame, or size to create the visual part. 
This can be done using

```
CGRectMake()
```

as you probably already know.

2: adding the view on top of the view as a subview.
This can be done by

```
[self.view addSubview:viewA/viewB];
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I commented saying I fixed the issue by initializing with a CGRect. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: no problem, just putting out a global reminder becasue I can't remember how many times i've forgotten to add the subview and spent hours confused haha